# How do I overlay a Donut Chart over a Geo Chart using google-react-chart in React Js

Tags: reactjs, react-google-charts

How do I overlay a Donut Chart over a Geo Chart using google-react-chart in React Js. Is is even possible to do without using CSS properties. By passing some data or function or event to Geo Chart.

To add a Donut Chart to the active regions of my Geo Chart to display data.